# How do pwd and . determine the current path differently?

Tags: directory, pwd

Is it mainly because `pwd` is not a builtin, while `.` is builtin to the bash shell?

For example, they differ in the following example:

```
/tmp/ttt$ mv ../ttt ../tttt
/tmp/ttt$ pwd
/tmp/ttt
/tmp/ttt$ cd .
/tmp/tttt$
```

Comment: `pwd` can be a builtin. `type pwd` returns `pwd is a shell builtin` under bash-4.2.47-3.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: This `.` is a directory.  The shell `.` builtin is a synonym of `source` command and is not what you are seeing in this question.

Answer (score 9):

`.` is not a bash (or any other shell) built-in. Each and every directory has entries `.` and `..` in it. You can verify by cd'ing to some arbitrary directory and doing `ls -lia` .  You will see `.` and `..` entries. I had you use the '-i' flag on `ls` to get inode numbers: note them for `.` and `..`. Go up a directory, but doing `cd ..` or `cd /something/soemthingelse/whatever`. Do `ls -lia` again. Notice that the inode number of `.` is identical to that of `..` in your first listing. Every directory has directories in it when created, named "." and "..". The "." entry has the same inode number as the directory's name does in its parent directory. The ".." entry is always the parent directory. If you do `ls -li /` you will see that "." and ".." have the same value.

This convention eliminates the need for special case code to reference the current directory: it's always named ".". It eliminates the need for special case code to "go up one directory": it's always "..". The only special cases are the root directory, and network-mounted filesystems. The filesystem root has "." and ".." with the same inode number, not different. Network-mounted filesystems have a discontinuity in inode numbers at the mount point, and behavior depends on what the remote filesystem is, and what protocol is used to mount it.

As far as the change in prompt, when you invoked `mv ../ttt ../tttt`, you actually renamed your shell's working directory. You didn't invoke a shell command that checks working directory until you did `cd  .`, so the intervening `pwd` reports the old name, `/tmp/tt`.

Comment: What are inode numbers for, why would you ever worry about listing them?

Comment: In Unix, Linux and other filesystems, an inode number is actually a file's identifier to the operating system. Depends on the filesystem, but there's usually a very quick way to go from inode number to the disk block that the inode lives. The inode itself is the on-disk structure representing a file: ownership, permissions, which data blocks contain file's data, access times, etc. A directory is just a mapping from a textual name to an inode number, the quick lookup of disk block from inode number allows the OS to get data and metadata quickly.

Comment: @BruceEdiger: I agree with everything you said here, but I don't see a response to the implicit question, "Why does `cd .` cause my shell prompt to change?"

Comment: @G-Man - thanks for the intelligent critique. I added a paragraph to explain that, I hope it's adequate.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using Bash which has [`pwd`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) as a builtin<sup>1</sup>, what happens is that the `cd` command triggers the shell to update the information regarding the current directory. Until you run `cd`, the shell will think that the current directory hasn't changed, so it doesn't try to get its new path.

By the way, to expand a bit on Gnouc's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147715/1174), the Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6 on [environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) says:

> `PWD`
>   [...] shall represent an absolute pathname of the current working directory. It shall not contain any filename components of dot or dot-dot. The value is set by the [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cd.html) utility.

On the other hand, if you'll run the external `/bin/pwd` command, you'll get the new name of the current directory. Why does this happen? The [`pwd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/pwd-invocation.html) command from **coreutils** does some sanity checks of the `PWD` environment variable and doesn't print it if it's invalid. The details can be found 
in the source code of the [`logical_getcwd`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/pwd.c?id=v8.23#n297) function (from coreutils version 8.23).

Another command you can use to the get the cannonical path of the current directory is `readlink -f .` <sup>2</sup>.

```
[ciupicri@host ttt]$ pwd
/tmp/ttt
[ciupicri@host ttt]$ mv ../ttt ../tttt
[ciupicri@host ttt]$ pwd
/tmp/ttt
[ciupicri@host ttt]$ /bin/pwd
/tmp/tttt
[ciupicri@host ttt]$ readlink -f .
/tmp/tttt
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Running `type pwd` can confirm this.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> From the [readlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html) man page: `-f`, `--canonicalize` canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; all but the last component must exist.</sup>

Comment: so `mv` doen't update the current path, but `cd` will?

Comment: Is `.` always updated immediately, while `pwd` isn't?

Comment: Yes `mv` doesn't make the shell to update its current directoty info.
`.` is a special subdirectory pointing to the directory itself which means that `cd .` changes to the same directory.

Comment: Note that calling `pwd -P` (Physical) will report the correct directory, even if it is a shell builtin (tested inside bash). And, after `pwd -P` reports the correct value, the memory value gets updated and plain `pwd` will reort it correctly also.

Answer (score 3):

`pwd` will print the value of `$PWD` if it contains an absolute pathname that does not have dot `.` or dot-dot `..`. From POSIX [pwd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html) definition:

```
-L
    If the PWD environment variable contains an absolute pathname of the 
    current directory that does not contain the filenames dot or dot-dot, 
    pwd shall write this pathname to standard output. Otherwise, if the PWD 
    environment variable contains a pathname of the current directory that 
    is longer than {PATH_MAX} bytes including the terminating null, and the 
    pathname does not contain any components that are dot or dot-dot, it is 
    unspecified whether pwd writes this pathname to standard output or 
    behaves as if the -P option had been specified. Otherwise, the -L option 
    shall behave as the -P option.
```

By default, `pwd` use `-L` option so it will print value of current `PWD`, which is set when you use `cd`. When you `mv` the current directory to new path, `PWD` still not change, so you will get the old pathname.

You can have some ways to get the right new pathname:

- Using `-P` option: `pwd -P`
- Using `/proc`: `ls -l /proc/self/cwd`

**Note**

As POSIX definition for variable [PWD](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03), if an application set or unset value of `PWD`, the behaviors of the `cd` and `pwd` are unspecified.

```
% cuonglm at /tmp/ttt
% PWD=/home/cuonglm
% cuonglm at ~
% pwd
/tmp/ttt
% cuonglm at ~
% pwd -P
/tmp/ttt
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to run `pwd -P`, running the external command can be good enough, i.e. `/bin/pwd` will print the new directory name.

Comment: Because `/bin/pwd` use `-P` option by default if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` isn't set. This is just my habit when use `pwd -P`.

Comment: Running `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/pwd` or `env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 pwd` makes no difference. The new directory is still printed.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: It must be defined in compile time, see:http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/pwd.c

Comment: [`pwd.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/pwd.c?id=v8.23) has `bool logical = (getenv ("POSIXLY_CORRECT") != NULL);` which suggests it's looking for an environment variable.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you see that it set value of boolean variable logical base on `POSIXLY_CORRECT` value?

Comment: It means that the `pwd` command depends on the *environment variable* named `POSIXLY_CORRECT`.

Comment: @cuonglm The reason that the builtin `pwd` reports an incorrect value is that the shell keeps an idea of the PWD in memory. Which could get out of sync with reality on corner cases. Call `pwd -P` and `pwd` will report the correct value. That `/bin/pwd` reports the correct value is because it has no notion of the value kept in memory by the shell. The memory value has absolutely no relation to any POSIXLY variable.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: No, it had. Running `/bin/pwd` the shell need to fork child process, which inherited the shell environment variables, include `PWD`. In all case, setting `PWD` will lead to unspecified behavior. Try the last example with `/bin/pwd` instead `pwd`, you got the same result (in `bash`).

Comment: @cuonglm The "unspecified behavior" is pure POSIX theory. In practice all shells do set PWD when `cd .` is executed.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: I didn't see your point. POSIX explicit state that *the shell* and *cd* assign value to `PWD` is legal thing, other application attempt to assign to `PWD` will lead to unspecified behavior from `cd` and `pwd`.

Comment: @cuonglm What you mean is that `/usr/bin/env PWD=/no/real/path pwd` should fail? The command `env` changed PWD and is not `shell` or `cd`.